# Code will never be executed Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

A preprocessor defined

```
  #define SIMULATE(navigationController) { if ( PREVALUE)  {  NSLog(@" After using navigationController :Success");return 1; } else  {NSLog(@" After using navigationController :Failed"); return 0;} }
```

While using it  in implementation

```
SIMULATE(self.navigationController);
```

Error shows

> Code will never be executed

Answer (score 1):

the Return Statements on macro caused the error.

> `#define SIMULATE(navigationController) { if ( PREVALUE) { NSLog(@" After using navigationController :Success");`**return 1;**`} else {NSLog(@" After using navigationController :Failed"); >`**return 0;**  `}}`

So remove these return statements

```
 #define SIMULATE(navigationController) { if ( PREVALUE)  {  NSLog(@" After using navigationController :Success"); } else  {NSLog(@" After using navigationController :Failed");} }
```

Comment: not at all, just shared so that someone else doesn't have to loose time. FYI there is an option to answer own's question. And you are welcome to share better solution than mine